# What is peer,node and peer node start in hyper ledger v0.6?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

What is peer and node in hyper ledger and also what peer node start will do?
what is the meaning of peer and node and how it can use in hyperledger

Answer (score 1):

unless you have a business requirement to pursue the v0.6 architecture, you should definitely pivot to v1.0 and the current stack.

To answer your question, there are two important entities to consider in a Fabric network (there are many components in the network, but we'll stick with two for now).  You have peers and orderers.  We tend to use the term peer and peer node interchangeably; they are the same thing.  You may also come across orderer and orderer node; again they are the same thing.

All peer nodes in Fabric v1.0 architecture are validating and committing peers (i.e. they maintain a ledger and run validation checks against blocks of transactions before appending to their ledger and updating world state). Ordering nodes do what you expect they might - play a central role in the ordering of transactions.  We don't need to delve into the specific role of orderers, but as a quick synopsis: responsible for accepting broadcasts of incoming transactions and responsible for delivering blocks of transactions to peers on a channel; with a kafka implementation, the ordering node(s) will actually relay the txs to the appropriate partition in the kafka cluster.  Ok enough on that.

Peer node start is simply the command to launch a peer container.  If you inspect a docker-compose file, you'll notice there is a command variable where `peer node start` is passed.